# Trouble with Anaconda installation

Tags: anaconda

So I recently installed anaconda on my macOS and now that I'm trying to see if anaconda is working, I see that its not working... I typed

```
conda list
```

into terminal and it gives me this message:

```
:-bash: conda: command not found:
```

Im not sure exactly what to do, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Where's your anaconda installed? can you go to that folder and try it? you should see something like this:

## packages in environment at /Users/.../anaconda:

if that doesn't work, can you try the GUI (Anaconda navigator) and see if it loads?